# Laravel 5 Excel Import to View

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using maatwebsite Laravel Excel and what I’m trying to do is import a csv and then display the results in a view.

I have no problem with importing the CSV and then dumping the results like so:

```
object(Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\RowCollection)#464 (2) {
  ["title":protected]=>
  string(9) "Worksheet"
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection)#472 (2) {
      ["title":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "Owen Kelley"
        ["age"]=>
        float(29)
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection)#473 (2) {
      ["title":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "Jim Jones"
        ["age"]=>
        float(50)
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    object(Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection)#474 (2) {
      ["title":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(10) "Sally Anne"
        ["age"]=>
        float(35)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code in my controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $results = Excel::load('public\uploads\file.csv', function($reader) {

        $reader->select(array('name', 'age'))->get();


    });

    return view('excel.show', compact('results'));

}
```

As I mentioned earlier If I change: `return view('excel.show', compact('results'));`
To

```
$results->dump();
```

Then I can see all the data in the table but I have no idea how to pass this data along to a view.

Can anyone help me with this?

I know this is something I should know already if I’m trying to accomplish this task but I am still very new to coding and am on a tight deadline.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you share your view file? What is the output when you return view?

Answer (score 1):

If `$results->dump()` works passing it to a view will very likely also work.

My guess is that Laravel can't find excel.show in your views. Can you show us the excel.show file, and verify the permissions are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
   $file= "test.xls";
    $data = Excel::load($file, function($reader) {

        foreach($reader->toArray()[0] as $row){             

        }
    })->get()->toArray()[0];

    return view('upload_load',compact('data'));
```

Comment: Please check your answer's code. It looks like that is a dangling end-of-comment macro.